# Why is virtual member function being called from base class instead of a subclass

Tags: c++, templates, coliru

I was writing a short snippet of code to figure out how I would store different template specializations into one data structure (e.g. `vector`). I'm aware of `tuple` but that's not good because I want to be able to append specializations after the `tuple` was constructed.

Below is a snippet of code that I came up with. In short, my idea was to have every template specialization inherit from a common `class Element` and then store such instances into a `vector<Element>`. That worked, but now when I access that data from `vector`, I access it as an `Element`. I need some way to find out which `Element` is paired with which template specialization.

Using `typeid` directly on elements from the `vector` returns the base type. I tried to work around that by having a member function `runtime_type` return that information from the subclass. Unfortunately, it's not working because the member function from `SparseSet<T>` is not overriding the virtual member function from the base class. I'm not sure why.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <algorithm>

class Element
{
public:
    virtual const std::type_info& runtime_type()
    {
        std::cout << " Called base ";
        return typeid(*this);
    }

    virtual ~Element() = default;
};

template<class T>
class SparseSet : public Element
{
public:
    T param;

    const std::type_info& runtime_type() override
    {
        std::cout << " Called derived ";
        return typeid(*this);
    }
};

class Manager
{
public:
    std::vector<Element> elements;

    template<class T>
    bool has()
    {
        const auto it = std::find_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), [](auto &element) {
            std::cout << "typeid(element) = " << element.runtime_type().name() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "typeid(T) = " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
            return typeid(element) == typeid(T); 
        });
        return it != elements.end();
    }
};

int main()
{   
    SparseSet<int> ss_int;
    ss_int.param = 3;

    SparseSet<char> ss_char;
    ss_char.param = 'a';

    Manager manager;

    manager.elements.push_back(ss_int);
    manager.elements.push_back(ss_char);

    std::cout << manager.has<SparseSet<int>>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the snippet above, using the online compiler [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) (`g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`), I get the following output.

```
typeid(element) =  Called base 7Element
typeid(T) = 9SparseSetIiE
typeid(element) =  Called base 7Element
typeid(T) = 9SparseSetIiE
0
```

Comment: Can you explain the situation and after that I'll close the question myself if I agree it's a duplicate? EDIT: I did read the link you provided but all I got from it was "lost information when you view something as base class".

Comment: @Spidey: "*Can you explain the situation*" The situation is, you're slicing the object.

Comment: @Spidey: Your `vector` stores `Element`. C++ can't store `Element` subclasses in a `vector`, they're always just `Element`. When you `push_back` a `SparseSet`, it slices it down to an `Element`. If you want to store "`Element` or a subclass of `Element`, you're probably best off making a `vector` of `std::unique_ptr<Element>`, which is a bit more of a pain (you'll have to wrap on insert, use dereferencing after indexing to do anything useful), but since pointers (and references) can refer to parent or child classes, it'll allow your child class to function as itself.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<Element> elements;
```

This means that `elements` is a `vector` of instances of the class `Element`, period. When a `vector` allocates memory, for example, it allocates contiguous space leaving `sizeof(Element)` for each instance. How can that be used to hold an instance of `SparseSet`?

You may want to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>>`, since a `unique_ptr<Element>` can hold a pointer to a `SparseSet`.

Comment: And this how a question should be answered. Not "you're slicing objects" but rather explaining how exactly am I doing it. Thank you David and ShadowRanger.